# How to create map with graticule with geoserver

Tags: geoserver, grids-graticules

I wonder if it is possible to render maps with graticule like this one using geoserver, if not what kind of FOSS4G could do the task in server side.
[image]

Comment: There seems to be an unofficial patch for creating graticule https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-5661.

Comment: MapServer has an official support http://mapserver.org/mapfile/grid.html

Comment: i wish i could find something like geoserver printing module that support graticules